# Existence of free abelian subgroup and isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am trying to prove the following question:

*Given is $G$ an abelian group and $F$ a free abelian group. Let $\varphi: G \rightarrow F$ an epimorphism. Show that there exsit a free abelian subgroup $F'\subset G$ with $ker\varphi \oplus F'=G$ such that $\varphi \mid _ {F'} :F'\rightarrow F$ is a group isomorphism.*

How do we prove the existence of $F'$? I know that the subgroups of free abelian groups are free. The epimorphism induces a bijection between the set of subgroups of $F$ and the set of the subgroups of $G$ which contain $ker \varphi$.

Can anybody help me with this question, please? I appreciate any hints and comments. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Show that it is sufficient to find a map $\psi:F \to G$ such that $\phi \circ \psi =Id_F$ (consider $Im(\psi)$). Now if $S$ is a basis of $F$, a map from $F$ to $G$ is determined by a function (of sets) $f:S \to G$. Moreover, you want $\phi \circ f=Id_S$, so you don't have a lot of choices left for $f$.

Can you take it from here ?